# python list counting elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

I have a code as below

How can I find that abc is a list made up of lists?

Whats wrong with my map function?

I want my function to return count of each element in my input list divided by length of my list.

Something like

```
{'brown': 0.16666666666666666, 'lazy': 0.16666666666666666, 'jumps': 0.16666666666666666, 'fox': 0.16666666666666666,  'dog': 0.16666666666666666, 'quick': 0.16666666666666666}
```

My code:

```
quickbrownfox1=['quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'lazy', 'dog']
print quickbrownfox1


def tf(tokens):
   
    abc=([[x,(tokens.count(x))] for x in set(tokens)])
    print type(abc)#how to know that abc is made up of lists
    print type(abc[1])
    answer=abc.map(lambda input:(input(0)),input(1)/len(tokens)))
    
    return answer
    #return <FILL IN>

print tf((quickbrownfox1)) # Should give { 'quick': 0.1666 ... }
#print tf(tokenize(quickbrownfox)) # Should give { 'quick': 0.1666 ... }
```

## _______________________________________

update 1

I updated my code as below. I get result `[('brown', 0), ('lazy', 0), ('jumps', 0), ('fox', 0), ('dog', 0), ('quick', 0)]` any idea why? If i do `return return list(map(lambda input: (input[0], input[1]), abc))`, it gives correct result - `[('brown', 1), ('lazy', 1), ('jumps', 1), ('fox', 1), ('dog', 1), ('quick', 1)]`

```
from __future__ import division
quickbrownfox1=['quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'lazy', 'dog']

def islistoflists(i):
    if isinstance(i, list):
        if len(i) > 0 and all(isinstance(t, list) for t in i):
            return True
    return False


def tf(tokens):

    print(islistoflists(tokens))

    abc = ([[x,tokens.count(x)] for x in set(tokens)])
    return list(map(lambda input: (input[0], input[1] / len(tokens)), abc))

print tf(quickbrownfox1)
```

---

update 2

I am using pyspark/spark. Could that be a reason for issues that i am facing in update1?

Comment: `is a list made up of lists` ? Make a for loop on abc then check every element with `type()`. If all of them lists, then you got what you want.

Comment: [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) is a build-in function, not a method, so `abc.map` it will not work, you have to use as `map(function, abc)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counter solution will definitely be better. Your use of `tokens.count` gives the code quadratic time complexity. Heres your code fixed up. You should note that `map` is a standalone function, not a member function of a list or any other type.

```
from __future__ import division
quickbrownfox1=['quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'lazy', 'dog']

def islistoflists(i):
    if isinstance(i, list):
        if len(i) > 0 and all(isinstance(t, list) for t in i):
            return True
    return False


def tf(tokens):

    print(islistoflists(tokens))

    abc = ([[x,tokens.count(x)] for x in set(tokens)])
    return list(map(lambda input: (input[0], input[1] / len(tokens)), abc))

print tf(quickbrownfox1)
```

To test if you have a list of lists, you can use `isinstance` to check the type of the parent object and if its a list and has at least one element in it, you can loop through them using `isinstance` to check if each child object is a list.

Note that I made your function return a list of tuples, implying that the items are read only, but you could make it return a list of lists by changing the line.

```
return list(map(lambda input: [input[0], input[1] / len(tokens)], abc))
```

If you look at it closely you'll see that a set of parenthesis have been substituted for square brackets, making each element a list.

If you have a older version of python 2 that does not support the `from __future__ import division` import you can uses the following workaround to force float division to occur.

```
return list(map(lambda input: (input[0], (input[1] * 1.0) / len(tokens)), abc))
```

Comment: I tried your approach. I get an answer `[('brown', 0), ('lazy', 0), ('jumps', 0), ('fox', 0), ('dog', 0), ('quick', 0)]` when i use `list(map(lambda input: (input[0], int(input[1])/len(tokens) ), abc))`. My abc is `[['brown', 1], ['lazy', 1], ['jumps', 1], ['fox', a], ['dog', 1], ['quick', 1]]`

Comment: i am follwoing a MOOC and pyspark. Not sure about the python version!

Comment: Use `float(input[1])` to force float division.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I think you're asking you could do something like

```
token_size = len(tokens)
word_counter_list = {}
for word in tokens:
    if word in word_counter_list:
        word_counter_list[word] += 1
    else:
        word_counter_list[word] = 1

for word, amount in word_counter_list:
    print("The word " + word + " was used " + str(amount/token_size)
```

That being said the question isn't very clear since you're mentioning list type() but showing percentage of word frequency in a list

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this fairly easily with a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
@>>> from collections import Counter
@>>> c = Counter(['quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'lazy', 'dog'])
@>>> total = sum(c.values())
@>>> result = dict()
@>>> for key, value in c.items():
@...   result[key] = value/total
@... 
@>>> result
{'dog': 0.16666666666666666, 'quick': 0.16666666666666666, 'fox': 0.16666666666666666, 'brown': 0.16666666666666666, 'jumps': 0.16666666666666666, 'lazy': 0.16666666666666666}
```

or, to make it super pythonic:

```
dict([ (key, value/total) for key,value in c.items() ])
```

Comment: it probably doesn't help that `list.map` is not a function; you are presumably looking for the [built-in function map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

Comment: Alternatively, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions); much, much more readable and pythonic than lambdas.